# Let $V={10}$ be the set of one element only. Is it possible to make $V$ a vector space...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V={10}$ be the set of one element only. Is it possible to make $V$ a vector space by introducing proper operations $+$  and scalar multiplication? If yes, enter 10+10. Here + is the vector space addition, not the usual addition of real numbers. If this is not possible, please explain why.

Comment: Any one-element vector space will be $\{x\}$ where $x$ is the additive identity of your vector space (usually denoted by "$0$").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible: $10+10=10$ and, for each real $\lambda$, $\lambda10=10$. It becomes a $0$-dimensional real vector space.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for explaining this so clearly for me. I originally wrote down 0, but I thought I was wrong. I had to get some confirmation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Any nonempty set $X$ can be made a (trivial) vector space over any field $F$ as follows.</strike>

Select an element $z\in X$ (this will be the "origin").

For every $x,y\in X$, define $x+y=z$.

For every $x\in X$ and every $\lambda\in F$, define $\lambda x = z$.

**EDIT:** This is incorrect, striking out. See comments.

Comment: What happened to $1 x = x$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : You're right, it falls apart completely. I don't think this can be repaired by redefining $\lambda x = x$ either since then $0_Fx=0_S$ fails. Looks like I posted too hastily :/

Comment: Thanks for noticing your mistake.